# Solr query with a large exclusion list

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I need to add to my queries an exclusion of 50-300 documents.
When the exclusion list is less than 100 it works fine and doesn't heart performance much.
Once I reach around 200 IDS in the exclusion list it makes the query run significantly slower.
I've tried to put the exclusion list in a filter query but it didn't help.
I think parsing the list adds significant time.
Is there a way to define a fq once and then reference it by name (and not send it each time)?
Are there other solutions for large exclusions lists?
I've tried the "join" feature and it caused the query to run slower as well.

Note:
Don't forget to use the following query format:

```
fq:!id(1,2,3...1000)
```

which provides significant better results than the following:

```
fq= -(id:0 id:1 .. id:1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a [Filter Cache](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache) in your Solr config, the result of your large filter will be cached until the index changes.